# Java 7 watcherservice - filtering files to watch

Tags: java-7

I am using the watcher service and it works great. I need to only watch for files with a certain extension, e.g. .xml. How can I implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that there is no built-in file extension filter (like there is using the old java.io.FileFilter interface).  I solved this same issue by adding an "if" statement in my processing code like so:

```
// Watcher gives key and you get event...

WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
Path file = dir.resolve(ev.context());
if (isCorrectFileType(file)) {
    // Do you processing here.
}
```

And the simple check:

```
private boolean isCorrectFileType(Path file) {
    return (file.toString().endsWith(".xml"));
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use file.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml") since extension can be upper case in some scenarios.